# Single column of select boxes with varied options using jqGrid

Tags: jquery

Have a grid that needs to have select boxes with different option values in the same column.  For instance, in the test grid that was set up to trouble shoot this problem, the concept is to select one of the actors from a movie using a select box.  Each row has the data for a different movie.  Within each row the actors column has a different list of actors that need to be used to dynamically populate the select box for that row.  The actor list is set up as CSV, comma separated values, in the database:  I.E., Clint Eastwood, Tom Cruz, Vin Diesel.

From the testing done, it looks like once the column model is set up, it is only executed once per grid load, meaning that you can only get one set of options for all select boxes in the column.  Have successfully passed an html string with the desired values to the grid as returned data by setting up a loop block to generate the proper code in the php file that populates the grid, in this case myfirtgridajax.php, and while it displays as a functional select box with the proper values, it does not behave like a select box that was set in the column model up using

```
{... edittype:select, edit options:{value:{CE:'Clint Eastwood'... }}}
```

What is required is that a POST request be generated onChange or something with the same result, from the select box that will set another value in the database.  That is, if Clint Eastwood is selected, then a POST request needs to be generated to pass that value to another php page for processing.

My question is that while it looks like a hack setting event listeners on the select boxes that were created by passing an html string would work, is there a better way to do this?

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#displayresultstable').jqGrid({
        url:'../gridcalls/myfirstgridajax.php',
        datatype:'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['ID', 'movie', 'topic', 'rating','actors'],
        colModel :[
            {name:'ID', index:'ID', width:50},
            {name:'movie', index:'movie', width:200, editable:true},
                {name:'topic', index:'topic', width:350, editable:true},
            {name:'rating', index:'rating', width:50, editable:true },
            {name:'actors', index:'actors', width:350, editable:true }, 
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum:10,
        height: 'auto',
        rowList:[5,10,15],
        sortname:'ID',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        cellEdit: true,
        cellurl:'../editfirstgridajax.php',
        caption: 'Movie Greats'
    });
    $('#displayresultstable').jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', {view: true});
});
</script>

<table id='displayresultstable'>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>

<div id='pager'></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Still would like a non-hack solution, but have come up with a hack that works.

What you do is set up a conditional block in the AJAX call page that generates the HTML object, in this case a select box populated by the data from the actors column.  Used PHP explode(',',$myarray) to parse the data and a loop to set up the select options.  Then add the JavaScript needed for event handlers to pass selected values and call to another JavaScript function to pass the data, I'm using POST, to another PHP page to update the database.  With all that in place, I substituted the HTML string for the line json value of the cell(for a given row) or column(looking at the whole grid).

On the columnModel, you have to remove the editable:true.  Other wise it is possible for a user to click on a margin/padding space of one or two pixels that can not be hidden by the select button, no matter what height property I gave the select box, which results in the HTLM string being displayed in that cell.  Also you need to place all the JavaScript on the same code line as the selectbox, I used a variable set to the HTML string generated in my conditional block, otherwise the grid adds a line break, or rather what seems and acts like a line break to the table cell the select box is placed in.  This causes the format of the grid cells to have increased height.

```
$responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['ID'],$row['movie'], $row['topic'],$row['rating'],'<select id="actors'.$i.'"style="width:100%;"><option value="what the'.$therowid.'">ed</option><option value="zed">zed</option><option value="red">red</option></select><script>$("#actors'.$i.'").change(function(){var actorselected =$("#actors'.$i.' option:selected").val();alert("you changed select box actors'.$i.' with record id '.$therowid.'\nThe selected value is "+actorselected);});/script>');
```

The above code is from a static try not using the DB, but does demonstrate how it works.